# Check if GWT EventBus has an EventHandler or not

Tags: gwt

I add EventHandler each time View is initialized with following line:

```
AGWTService.App.getEventBus().addHandler(AnEvent.TYPE, this.AClass);
```

This results multiple event handling in the lifecyle of the application. However, there is no method to remove handler from EventBus or check if EventBus has already the EventHandler. In my case, EventBus is a static SimpleEventBus class:

```
private static final EventBus EVENT_BUS = GWT.create(SimpleEventBus.class);
```

I tried to wrap EventBus with ResettableEventBus, but didn't help. What is the correct way to deal with EventBus on a View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addHandler() method returns a HandlerRegistration the removeHandler() method of which you can use to remove your handler.

Comment: yes, this work! Thanks. It would be nice to provide the type of the handler to remove() method instead of removing all of them at once.

Comment: Only one handler is removed when you call HandlerRegistration#remove() - the one for which the HandlerRegistration object was returned.

Comment: Forgot to write, the exact method name is removeHandler().

Comment: Right, fixed the answer.